# Try to decoding Concox AT2 data

Tags: gps

I try to understand the message I received from Concox AT2 tracker but I got stuck in this
[image]

After successfully handle login message, I never received 0x12 protocol, the closest thing I got is a
0x2c protocol. This is a part of the message I received:

```
0x78,0x78,0x5d,0x2c,0x14,0x7,0x1d,0x0d,0x1b,0x34,0x01,0xfe,0x59,0x35,0xc8,0x00,0x36,0x5c,0x19,0x35,0xc8,0x00
```

The 6 byte data after the protocol byte correspond to date time like in the location data protocol, but the data after that doesn't seems correspond to location data.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Nervermind, I read the manual for the wrong device.